# Swift switch case let syntax - access function defined on nested enum

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I need to access a function defined on a nested enum. My setup is the following:

```
var currentlyShowingStepIndex:Int?
var allSetupSteps:[SetupStep] = []

enum SetupStep {
    case districtSetupStep(DistrictSetupStep), toolSetupStep(ToolSetupStep)

    enum DistrictSetupStep {
        case one, two, three
    }

    enum ToolSetupStep {
        case one, two, three

        func accessMe() -> Int {
            switch self {
                case one:
                    return 1
                case two:
                    return 2
                case three:
                    return 3
            }
        }
    }
}

if let index = currentlyShowingStepIndex {
    let currentStep = allSetupSteps[index]
    switch currentStep {
    case .districtSetupStep(_):
        print("asdf")

    // **** I have no idea for the syntax of the following, the code below does not work *****
    case .toolSetupStep(_) let toolStep:
        let numberNeeded = toolStep.accessMe()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the value "numberNeeded" above, but I have no idea what the syntax is to access it, or if it's even possible.

Comment: `case .toolSetupStep(let toolStep):`

Comment: Thank you. I've been googling for over an hour :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this function and its associated value with two syntaxes.

---

**First**:

```
case .toolSetupStep(let toolStep):
```

That is a common way but it has one draw back that in case you have many associated values you must mark all of them with `let` or `var`. It's useful when our properties could be neither `let` or `var` so you have flexability to mark each property.

**Second: (preferred one for me)**

We prefix enum case with type value we need (`let` or `var`).
This way you can define as much as you need of your associated values without prefixing each value with its value type.

```
case let .toolSetupStep(toolStep):
    //your code using tollStep
```

Assuming we have 3 associated values at toolSetupStep we can easily use them like that:

```
case let .toolSetupStep(toolStep,toolStep2,toolStep3):
```